# Providing custom object information when using console.log

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to have console.log return a customized format for objects it inspects?  Possibly by adding a special method of some sort to the object?

```
class Thing {
  constructor(num) {
    this.num = num;
  }

  specialConsoleMethodOfSomeSort() {
    return `the ${num}`;
  }
}

var t = Thing(1);
console.log(t);
// "the 1"
```

Comment: In Node, in browsers? `console.log` doesn't really have a standard, so it's different everywhere.

Comment: Hmmm...preferably node